# Many-to-one relation returns None object: SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-one

I'm trying to write Schedule class which contains records like this:
... session, base, engine declaration somewhere here...

```
class Schedule(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'schedule'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # and here i need ref to Station class
    station_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('station.id'))
    station = relationship('Station') # Also tried Station
    arr_time = Column(Time)

    def __init__(self, station_name, arrive_time):
         self.metadata.create_all()
         self.arrive_time = arrive_time

         # And now I'm trying to find station object by a given name
         # and add ref to it in self.station. 
         # The selection of a station works properly here:
         station = session.query(Station).filter(Station.name == station_name).first()
         # But on this statement I get an error: None object has no method 'append'
         self.station.append(station)
         session.add(self)
         session.commit()
```

After that I implement class 'Station'

```
class Station(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stations'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name
```

So, when I'm trying to add new Schedule record I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The one-to-many case (where the foreign key in the first class and relationsip in the second one) works correctly.

What's wrong with my code?

**Update:**
Also tried example from documentation:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base = declarative_base(engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))
    child = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.create_all()
    parent = Parent()
    session.add(parent)
    child = Child()
    session.add(child)
    print(hasattr(Parent, 'child'))
    print(hasattr(parent, 'child'))
    print(type(Parent.child))
    print(type(parent.child))
```

I get:

```
 >>> True
 >>> True
 >>> <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute'>
 >>> <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: Also get this error with example from documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it))
The problem was that as default `uselist` flag in constructor of relationship is set for `True`. 
But - I don't really understand why it is not written in documentation - in the case of many-to-one relation this flag is set for `False`.

So, to solve my problem I simply have to change this:

```
station = relationship("Station", uselist=True)
```

or use in constructor:

```
self.station = station
```

This completely solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I think the problem is that the relationship does not get triggered until you add and commit.

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base = declarative_base(engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))
    child = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.create_all()
    parent = Parent()
    session.add(parent)
    child = Child()
    session.add(child)
    session.commit() # IMPORTANT: this is necessary for relationship to work
    print(hasattr(Parent, 'child'))
    print(hasattr(parent, 'child'))
    print(type(Parent.child))
    print(type(parent.child))
```

The only line I added is

```
        session.commit() # IMPORTANT: this is necessary for relationship to work
```

Answer (score 0):

```
station = session.query(Station).filter(Station.name == station.name).first()
```

`self.station` is None....

Try to use debugger or just `print station` , `print self.station`

**Edit: Class Variable Scopes:**

There are 2 ways for class scope vars:

1. Instance variable - when using self, this is called instance variable and by that to each instance of that class you will have a copy of the variable.
2. Class attribute - in your case it's Schedule.station it's owned by the class, not the instances of the class.

Please refer to the [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) about namespace it will clear your problem.

Comment: No, station in not None))) And even if it is None, you are able to add it to any list: `x = []; x.append(None)` gives `[None]`. Error exists on `relationsip`, not on station itself.

Comment: this is the line that gives the error self.station.append(station) isn't it? that's what i understand from AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: sorry, I have misspelling in my code example here. `Station.name == station_name`, not `station.name`. In my code everything properly (I've typed this code here, not copied)

Comment: np:) just edit the post so it will be clear. also do you have self.station? and what is it's content?

Comment: self.station - is in fact request to the Schedule.station member, as I understand. Isn't it correct usage?

Comment: Well, if i try to use self.classmember I will get a copy of class member in my instance. So it should be of type `<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute'>`, such as in class. But in fact I get `<class 'NoneType'>`. I.e. property exists, but it is not defined.

Comment: I've added example from sqlalchemy documentation with exactly the same problem